# Managing fund of bot users

Tags: algorithmic-trading, hedge-fund, funds

I'm algotrading since 2018 and been profitable (not much, but consistent) since then.

This year I thinking in make a business around this bot. My only doubt is how do I manage the fund of all users? If I enter in all the signals my bot sends to everyone probably the market will be affected and probably the "last" user will not be able to get the price my bot generated the signal..

Anyone here has a approach similar to this and can help me?

Btw, I'm in the crypto trading :)

Comment: is your bot a trading strategy, and by users do you mean they follow your bot to replicate its strategy. what does your bot do and the signals it sends out

Comment: It's a bot that use websocket connection through a exchange and calculate in real time some indicators. Based in this indicators I can determine some buy and sell signals. For me, and only me, it's ok because I know how much I could buy or sell without moving the market too much, however, having more users using it I don't know how to proceed

Comment: Sorry for the point, but if your strategy is profitable your business shouldn't be selling that strategy... Conversely, you should find a good broker and leverage your strategy while keeping it as much secret as you can.

Comment: I'm not selling my strategy, my idea is to have a subscription service where I manage all the users through API keys from the exchange and execute their orders.